# How does Opencv MedianBlur actually work?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing

I've been working with a grayscale image that has a lot of Salt and Pepper noise and came to know that MedianBlur is very useful. So I used the Python version of Opencv(`cv2.medianBlur()`). It worked but didn't work in the way I wanted. So I was looking for the actual algorithm it worked on and got the following explanation:

If you have a kernel size(k) of 5, then for every 5(row count)x5(column count) square window, the central pixel of this window will get replaced by the Median value of all the elements in it. So, for instance, consider this window:

```
      [[11,  4, 17,  1,  5],
       [ 6, 14,  0, 12, 16],
       [24, 19, 13, 18, 23],
       [ 7, 11, 11, 10,  5],
       [10, 13, 23,  3,  0]]
```

Here, the central element, 13 will get replaced by the Median of all these elements, i.e. 11. Is this correct? If yes, what happens to the first 2 rows, since there can't be elements in the first two rows which are the central element for ANY window? As per my observation(comparing the original and processed image), the first two rows change too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`medianBlur()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.9/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga564869aa33e58769b4469101aac458f9) documentation, it uses `BORDER_REPLICATE` internally to process border pixels.

```
BORDER_REPLICATE 
Python: cv.BORDER_REPLICATE

aaaaaa|abcdefgh|hhhhhhh
```

So it repeats the bordering pixels until all pixels are the mid pixel of a window.

EDIT: To apply a kernel with a size of 5x5, the first pixel should be at the third row and column of the image. It means replicate the the border by two pixels. So your image becomes this internally:

```
  [[11, 11, 11,  4, 17,  1,  5,  5,  5],
   [11, 11, 11,  4, 17,  1,  5,  5,  5],
   [11, 11, 11,  4, 17,  1,  5,  5,  5],
   [ 6,  6,  6, 14,  0, 12, 16, 16, 16],
   [24, 24, 24, 19, 13, 18, 23, 23, 23],
   [ 7,  7,  7, 11, 11, 10,  5,  5,  5],
   [10, 10, 10, 13, 23,  3,  0,  0,  0],
   [10, 10, 10, 13, 23,  3,  0,  0,  0],
   [10, 10, 10, 13, 23,  3,  0,  0,  0]]
```

Comment: They don't have much documentation on BORDER_REPLICATE. As far as I understood, if you have a row, abcdefh where 'a' and 'h' are border pixels, then it will fill the row like aaaaaa|abcdefgh|hhhhhh. But how will it work for 2-dimensional windows? If I have a 2D window like [[13, 16, 18], [16, 17, 19], [20, 17, 18]], and I have to make it 5x5, how will it work?

Comment: The same, if you have `ab` it becomes `aabb,a|ab|b,aabb` in 2D. Extend the borders to left/right/top/bottom.

Comment: `[[13, 16, 18], [16, 17, 19], [20, 17, 18]]` becomes `[[13, 13, 16, 18, 18], [13, 13, 16, 18, 18], [16, 16, 17, 19, 19], [20, 20, 17, 18, 18], [20, 20, 17, 18, 18]]`

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase my comment: if I have the first 5 rows and first 5 columns of the input image, and I have to apply the median blur to it to change the first pixel value [0,0], how would it go? Given the first 5 rows and columns: [[13, 16, 18, 23, 14], [16, 17, 19, 19, 16], [20, 17, 18, 19, 16], [21, 14, 13, 13, 13], [16, 13, 14, 14, 14]]

Comment: @arghhjayy: Another way of explaining the `BORDER_REPLICATE` method: for any pixel outside of the image that you need in the computation, take the nearest image pixel.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain what happens to your original image with `BORDER_REPLICATE` for 5x5 kernel.

Comment: Thank you @ilke444 for the explanation and Cris, you too.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

> The median filter uses #BORDER_REPLICATE internally to cope with
>   border pixels, see #BorderTypes

Answer (score 0):

Here, the function cv2.medianBlur() computes the median of all the pixels under the kernel window and the central pixel is replaced with this median value. This is highly effective in removing salt-and-pepper noise. One interesting thing to note is that, in the Gaussian and box filters, the filtered value for the central element can be a value which may not exist in the original image. However this is not the case in median filtering, since the central element is always replaced by some pixel value in the image. This reduces the noise effectively. The kernel size must be a positive odd integer.